# Trouble with Request.Form inside .cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Trying to create a page that will have a drop down selector with three image names and when an image name is selected and you hit submit it will then display that image on the page.

I found an example of this here(Seems to be outdated): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/9-working-with-images

has: if(Request["photoChoice"] != null)

Read somewhere that the correction is Request.Form

```
@{ var imagePath = "";
    if (Request.Form["photoChoice"] != null)
        {
            imagePath = @"images\" + Request.Form["photoChoice"];
        }
}


<form method="post" action="">
    <div>
        I want to see:
        <select name="photoChoice">
            <option value="Photo1.jpg">Photo 1</option>
            <option value="Photo2.jpg">Photo 2</option>
            <option value="Photo3.jpg">Photo 3</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    <div style="padding:10px;">
        @if (imagePath != "")
        {
            <img src="@imagePath" alt="Sample Image" width="300" />
        }
    </div>
</form>
```

The first error I was having was: 
" Operator '!=' is ambiguous on operands of type 'StringValues' and 'null' "

adding (object) at the start of the Request there in the if statement

```
@{ var imagePath = "";
    if ((object)Request.Form["photoChoice"] != null)
        {
            imagePath = @"images\" + Request.Form["photoChoice"];
        }
```

Now I am getting another error "InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type" when I try to compile the site. It does refer to the If line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The link you refer to is used in asp.net, not in core.
>
> The main reason for the error is that you put the request.Form in the
>   wrong place. Your current requirements should put the code
>   into the `OnPost` method in the code behind.

There are many ways to implement this function in the core, but they need to be triggered in the `post` method in the code behind.

Please refer to [this](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms).

The simplest way is to `bind fields` in the code behind. Please refer to the following for details.

Page.cs:

```
public class ShowImagesModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public string imagePath { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string photoChoice { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            imagePath = "";

        }
        public void OnPost()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(photoChoice))
            {
                imagePath = @"images\" + photoChoice;
            }
        }

    }
```

View:

```
@page
@model WebApplication1_razor_page.ShowImagesModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ShowImages";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
} 
<h1>ShowImages</h1>

<form method="post" action="">
    <div>
        I want to see:
        <select asp-for="photoChoice" >
            <option value="Photo1.jpg">Photo 1</option>
            <option value="Photo2.jpg">Photo 2</option>
            <option value="Photo3.jpg">Photo 3</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    <div style="padding:10px;">
        @if (Model.imagePath != "")
        {
            <img src="@Model.imagePath" alt="Sample Image" width="300" />
        }
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the result:

[image]